# phpMyAdmin basic HTTP authorization

Tags: apache, http, phpmyadmin

I would like to know how to change my phpMyAdmin password with the HTTP authorization.

Answer (score 0):

The config file is located here:
`<phpmyadmin_root>/config.inc.php`

Change the `auth_type` as required. Check [here](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types) for available auth types.